# How to stop animation on background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have animation on background image in my website, specifically image is moving on left all the time but when image come to the end it start again. My problem is that when the image come to the end (left side) the edges are visible and I want when it come to the left side to go to the right, when it come to the right side..on the left again.

```
var x=0;
var y=0;

var banner = $("#loading");
banner.css('backgroundPosition', x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');

window.setInterval(function(){
banner.css('backgroundPosition', x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');
x--;
}, 90);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example animation:

```js
var x = 0;

var fps = 30;
var speed = 2;

var bannerWidth = 400;
var imageSize = 128;

setInterval(function() {
    x += speed;
    
    if (x >= bannerWidth-imageSize || x <= 0) {
     speed *= -1;
    }
    
    $("#banner").css("backgroundPosition", x + "px 0");
}, 1000/fps);
```

```css
#banner {
    width: 400px;
    height: 128px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/position-relative/social-1/128/google-icon.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner"></div>
```

I can modify the example if you provide your HTML & CSS.

Comment: I think that is not necessary to write the html and css code because it is background image of the whole website, i put id="loading" in the body tag to have access to the background image...the css is just for margins of the site...